# Change database authentication mode

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I have a SQL Server Express database on my desktop that I use to test an old classic asp program. I need to change the authentication method from Windows authentication to password authentication. I have changed the server from windows auth to SQL Server and Windows auth mode and restarted the server. I went into security and added a new login for the database set the name and login and the default db to the db I need to be able to use password to login to.  When I attempt to log in using SQL Authentication I get the error message

> CANNOT OPEN USER DEFAULT DATABASE. LOGIN FAILED.  LOGIN FAILED FOR USER ERROR 4064

I open the connection properties and changed the connect to db to the db for the password login and got the same message. I have searched the internet and tried ever solution I could find to no avail. What am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the string you are using to authenticate? Have you created user with password?

Comment: connect database engine->options->connection properties tab->change connect to database to master

Comment: Ok, see my answer at the second option. Probably your login has no rights at the deafult database or the it's no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

First of all see if the sql server was configured to received SQL Server Autentication (Mix Mode)

right clink at server at the management-> porperties -> security

choose the option below and restar the service

[image]

other commum problem to some connection it that the user was create with a wrong default database

open the security folder at the management-> Logins

Choose your the login and open the properties like this below

[image]

Tell me if it's works

Comment: I check all of this and I already had it set.  I opened the database properties I wanted us password login for went to files and and changed to owner to the user and that allowed me to log in as that user and only see the one database.

Comment: The next problem I have is I created a DSN for that table but it wont let the program login using the user name and password. Got any ideas about this.  Thanks for you help.